# How to show a numerical method is symmetric?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

This is the definition I've been given, say $y_n=y_{n-1}+h_n\phi(y_{n-1},y_n,h)$ then this method is symmetric if $\phi(u,v,h)=\phi(v,u,-h)$. If anyone can provide a worked out example of a numerical method that satisfies this property that would be great. I'm just looking for clarity of the concept. I've tried google and nothing

Comment: Both the midpoint method and the trapezoidal method should be easy to verify, one has $ϕ(u,v,h)=f((u+v)/2)$, the other $(f(u)+f(v))/2$, both symmetric, both not containing $h$, so invariant to a sign change in $h$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann can you help me out with new problem I just posted about? You seem to know this subject very well. 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4293390/finding-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-to-show-that-the-forward-euler-discretization-fo

Answer (score 0):

So there's some theory around symmetric methods, I refer you to Hairer's "Geometric Numerical Integration", all of this discussion pulls from that text! (so this is not my own work!) Anyway, there's a way you can take common methods and get symmetric methods from them.

#-------------------- **What does it mean to be (non)symmetic?** ---------------------#

**Symmetric:** The definition for symmetric is as you say.. if you take a negative time step from the end point do you arrive at the start? (i.e. symmetric if $\Phi(u,v,h)=\Phi(v,u,-h)$). This is the purple colored path in the image below.

**Non-symmetric:** Consider the forward Euler update for the autonomous ODE $\frac{dy(t)}{dt} = f(y)$.

Denote forward Euler as the map $\Phi_F(y,h)$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method#Derivation)
$$ y_1 = \Phi_F(y_0,h) =  y_0 + h f(y_0)$$
Step 1: Starting from $y_0$ update to $y_1$ using forward Euler (see image below).

Step 2: "turn around" and use the same map with a negative time step (see image!).
$$ y_2 = \Phi_F(y_1,-h) = y_1 - h f(y_1)$$

You can ask, when I "turned around" and went "forward" did I end up in the same spot? (i.e. $y_0 = y_2$). You'll see that, unless $f(y)$ is a constant, you did NOT end where you started! So forward Euler is NOT symmetric.

[image: Diagram of symmetric & non-symmetric updates.]

#----- **How do I get a symmetric update without "guess and test"?** -----#

**The Concept:** Now that we have a Non-symmetric update, let's see how to use it to get a symmetric update! Let's say you wanted determine the symmetric part of a matrix... what would you do? $M_{symmetric} = 1/2(M + M^T)$.

The same can be done for updates.
You would compute the adjoint update method (i.e. transpose) and compose the two functions together.

**Adjoint of forward Euler:** Start from forward Euler and rearrange the map so that you DO end up at the place you started.
$$ y_1 = \Phi_F(y_0,h) =  y_0 + h f(y_0)$$
$$ y_0 = y_1 - h f(y_0)$$
Recognize the backward Euler method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_Euler_method#Derivation)!
$$ y_0 = \Phi_B(y_0,y_1,-h)$$

**Function composition of method with its adjoint:**
$$y_1 = \Phi_B(y_1,y_{1/2},h/2) \circ \Phi_F(y_0,h/2) = \Phi_B(y_1,\Phi_F(y_0,h/2),h/2)$$
$$ y_{1/2} = \Phi_F(y_0,h/2) = y_0 + h/2 f(y_0)$$
$$ y_1 = \Phi_B(y_1,y_{1/2},h/2) = y_0 + h/2 f(y_0) + h/2 f(y_1)$$

You may recognize this as the trapezoid method!! Which as Lehmann showed in your comments is symmetric.

#-------- **Conclusions**--------#

Since you couldn't find anything on google, I have given you a reference material Hairer "Geometric Numerical Integration". I have also defined the symmetric concept for integrators and connected it to  the symmetric concept for matrices. I have provided you a way to use that concept to arrive at symmetric examples! Best of luck in your future integration endeavors!

Comment: Largely that is correct, but I think that you should work on notation, especially for the backwards method. I would make a bigger distinction between the method step operators and the step update terms. Then $y_1=\Phi_{BE}(y_0,h)$ is defined or constructed as the solution (closest to $y_0$) of $y_1=y_0+h\phi_{BE}(y_0,y_1,h)$. The construction as adjoint would then use the double time inversion in the index order and time step as solution of $y_0=\Phi_{FE}(y_1,-h)$, which written out in the method step gives $y_1=y_0-h\phi_{FE}(y_1,-h)$. It follows that $\phi_{BE}(y_0,y_1,h)=\phi_{FE}(y_1,-h)$.

Comment: Hey Lutz, I was definitely confusing t and h. I corrected it all to h's, Thanks!
Also stylistically, I prefer the $y_1 = \Phi_F(y_0,h)$ and $y_1 = \Phi_B(y_1,y_0,h)$ because it makes the implicit nature of Backward Euler evident to the reader. I put the $y_1$ as the first variable to emphasize that it's implicit.

Comment: I could see the argument to switch argument positions from $y_1 = \Phi_B(y_1,y_0,h) = y_0 + h f(y_1)$ to $y_1 = \Phi_B(y_0,y_1,h) = y_0 + h f(y_1)$ so that the order you write $y$'s in the addition matches the order you write the $y$'s in the argument. But these are very minute details.